# Замена переменной в mysql после завершения сессии

Tags: php

Есть база данных, в которой хранятся большие таблицы, привязанные к пользователям. Если один пользователь редактирует свою таблицу, то у таблицы в бд устанавливается флаг, чтоб другие пользователи не могли открыть данную таблицу (таблицы в виде экселя заполняемые полностью динамически, как в гугл докс). Если пользователь прекращает работу с данной таблицей самостоятельно - нажимает кнопку завершения и перехода в другой раздел сайта, то всё хорошо. Если он просто закрывает вкладку / забывает о странице и сессия сама закрывается / уходит с данной вкладки на другой сайт, то флаг так и остаётся установленным и как его сбросить я не знаю.

Comment: Лучше о механизме записи с историей подумайте, как на википедии или тут, в SO. Нехорошо надолго что то блокировать. А вообще можно сделать ajax который пока страница открыта раз в 30 сек. например шлет серверу - я еще редактирую. сервер обновляет время лока в БД. если другой пользователь хочет открыть таблицу, смотрим время лока, если более 10 мин скажем не обновлялось, значит редактор потерян, можем перехватить блокировку

Comment: Быстрее всего так и сделаю, буду хранить время использования таблицы, тогда отпадает привязка к пользователю. Спасибо.

Comment: Только это все равно криво. Я открываю страницу на редактировние и иду пить чай. А потом я отвлекаюсь на другое окно браузера, не закрывая данное и вообще ухожу гулять, а комп я никогда не выключаю ... Она так со мной месяц может в блоке провисеть ...

Comment: Не не, всё нормально реализовано :)) таблица абсолютно динамическая, то бишь кнопки сохранить нету, все данные передаются при определённых условиях сразу. Обновление сессии я не запускаю, просто при каждой транзакции с сервером обновляю время в базе на данную таблицу. Если пользователь не активен больше получаса, то сессия слетает и пользователю в любом случае нужен перелогин (да да, всё так сложно), соответственно отталкиваясь от время слёта сессии сделал поиск и сортировку таблиц с включением времени последнего апдейта плюс пол часа :)

Comment: OMG, сессия это лишняя зависимость в данной задаче. Где у вас отметка о занятости конкретной таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема сродни определению "находится ли пользователь online". Самое простое решение без дополнительных зависимостей — считать, что пользователь отключился, если нет от него вестей более чем **N** секунд. То есть вам нужна не логическая метка Да/Нет, а значение типа timestamp.

Чтобы поддерживать эту метку в актуальном состоянии, придется "пинговать" javascript-ом со страницы редактирования раз в **M < N** секунд и на сервере апдейтить метку.

**UPDATE**: @Mike справедливо отметил в комментарии, что кто-то может оставить открытой страницу надолго, а фактически ничего не делать. Это не должно быть поводом для блокировки. Так что пожалуй лучше не "пинговать", а апдейтить метку занятости только при реальных изменениях. Или пинговать только если пользователь проявляет какую-то активность на странице — отслеживать клавиатурные события.

**UPDATE 2-й и последний**: Речь не о какой-то сессии, а об актуальности состояния системы. Это ответ на вопрос:

> флаг так и остаётся установленным и как его сбросить я не знаю

Вместо отметки `"Иванов редактирует таблицу А"` следует хранить отметку `"в 2015-01-23 10:34:55 Иванов редактирует таблицу А"`. И если отметка слишком старая, считать её неактуальной.
Если бы вы когда-то вычисляли список пользователей онлайн, вы бы увидели аналогию.

Comment: Проблема очень слабо связана с "нахождением пользователя онлайн",  так как у каждого пользователя может быть минимум от 3х до бесконечности таблиц, а запрещать на просмотр необходимо только редактируемую. Таблица представляет собой отчёт за год, соответственно даже если у пользователя всего 1 выделенное пространство, то у него таблица раскидана по годам, а каждый год хранится отдельно. Поэтому решение предложденное Mike оптимально - обновлять таблицу при изменениях и не обновлять на автомате сессию

Comment: Жаль, что не поняли моё предожение. Ни про какую сессию я вообще не упоминал.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы уточнить непонятные моменты, вы спроецировали предложение на свой багаж знаний. Получилась фигня.